# Print to PDF with Ghostscript: output is PS, not PDF (using MFILEMON)

Tags: windows-10, pdf, printing, ghostscript

### Shouldn't PDF files start with %PDF?

I'm attempting to use [MFILEMON](https://sourceforge.net/p/mfilemon/activity/) 1.5.2, as recommended [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15284045/7257404), and GhostScript 9.26 to create a "Print to PDF" printer on a fresh Windows 10 installation.

I previously did this on a previous laptop, with **no issues**. Not sure what's wrong with my syntax. I'm using the directions here:

- https://kutana.fogbugz.com/?W2013

[image: screenshot]

The directions say:

> User command `"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.21\bin\gswin64c.exe" -dBATCH -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage -r600 -sOutputFile="%f" -`  Note how the version number 9.21 appears in the executable file path.

> Note also that the command ends with an important  trailing hyphen.

> Use pipe - on Windows 7 and 8 check this - on Win 10 leave it unchecked.
> Leave the other fields at their default settings.
> Click [ OK ]

(I substituted 9.26 for 9.21).

I've tried the setup process BOTH checked and unchecked and either way, I get a file which is a PS file, not a PDF.  A PDF reader won't read the file:

[image]

The Windows Test Page, as a PDF, starts with the following:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%Title: Test Page
%%Creator: PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2
%%CreationDate: 8/5/2019 12:35:10
%%For: myname
%%BoundingBox: (atend)
%%Pages: (atend)
%%Orientation: Portrait
%%PageOrder: Special
[etc.]
```

**Shouldn't this start with %PDF?**  It looks like the output file is getting passed through the GS console (gswin64c) **without being** converted to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually just an updated means of printing pre PDF from the earier days of PostScript cross Platform printing.

On Linux Mac or Dos you would set up PrintDrivers to generate Postscript Files and then use a Port Redirector such as RedMon, NOTE do NOT use RedMon in Windows 10 or 11+ itself admits not suitable, hence MFileMon is preferred.

Adobe PDF generation also did similar by Printout to Postscript then Distil (using a background Distiller Application into PDF.

So core to the Process is print a Postscript File then use a File Monitor to RESEND that as a conversion from Postscript to PDF.

### Q)

How can it fail in second stage to push a file though a command line converter like GhostScript.

### A)

several unknowns such as
Version 9.27 (2019-04-03) was the newest at time of OP question but syntax changes mean take caution about changes in updated syntax.

I am using using 10+ (currently 10.02.01) so lets test PS 2 PDF functionality

`cd /d "/path to GS exec folder/bin"`

mine is odd but C:\Users\owners name\Downloads\Apps\PDF\GS\10.01.2\gs-10.01.2\bin
also 32bit but makes no difference for tests

`gswin32c.exe -oescher.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -f ..\examples\escher.ps`

reply

> GPL Ghostscript 10.01.2 (2023-06-21)
> Copyright (C) 2023 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
> This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
> see the file COPYING for details.
> Loading NimbusSans-Regular font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular... 4444880 3010829 1781400 489115 2 done.

C:\Users\lez\Downloads\Apps\PDF\GS\10.01.2\gs-10.01.2\bin>

so looks good, so far, the PS was converted into PDF without any problems!
run  the cmd>`escher.pdf`    and your default PD viewer (could be GS itself :-) will load the file as a PDF [image]

I would also now recommend use a newer MFileMon currently 1.6.1 (https://github.com/lomo74/mfilemon)

Sadly the instructions are very old 2009 and the latest binary release version (1.6.1) does not include some more recent updates !! and installation also seems very old.

Anyway to test 1.6.1 after install it, lets set the correct parameters. The app is unusual in that there is no start icon as its a acting as a port service, so needs configuring via printers.

Yet another oddity is you dont see it till you add it so here with other print silent to PDF files I need to click add port ! and now I can use it !

[image] [image]
[image]
Always a good idea to ensure a test print is done as part of installation
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi KJ, thanks for working on this answer.   I understand that "four years later, with different versions of the software, this works on your computer."   — This is a good reminder that there may be **newer versions** of the software available in case someone else has a similar problem.